# Access to PIT (?) IO ports 44h and 46h - what do those ports do?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, ioports

I was disassembling an MS-DOS .com application and came across some port access which I don't understand. More precisely, via the `IN` instruction, values are read from the following ports.

```
40h
44h
46h
```

The documentation found [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/I/O_Ports) mentions ports `40h-47h` belong to the 'Programmable Interval Timer', but the [details](https://wiki.osdev.org/PIT) elaborate only on ports `40h-43h`.

From the disassembled context I would guess that the input is then used as pseudorandom numbers.

I also found [this reference](https://www4.cs.fau.de/Lehre/WS07/V_BS/Uebungen/oostubs/web/aufgaben/aufgabe5/timer.shtml) (in German) which does not mention the 4 other ports. Does anybody know the exact function of these ports, ideally with a reference?

Edit: To provide more context, the part of the disassembled application looks as follows.

```
in  al, 46h
mov cl, 03h
div cl
mov bl, ah

in  al, 44h
div cl
mov bh, ah

mov dx, 40h
in  al, dx
div cl
```

The application is [this](http://256bytes.untergrund.net/demo/586) tiny effect; the read values are used to set the VGA palette RGB values to be colorful at best, interesting at worst.

Comment: According to [this table](https://bochs.sourceforge.io/techspec/PORTS.LST), 44h is a third timer present on PS/2 and EISA computers.  Perhaps the port address is decoded incompletely on other computers and 44h–47h just map to 40h–43h?

Comment: understand that disassembling x86 is rough at best even with great tools.   Have you walked the code in execution order to confirm that the disassembly is correct-ish?

Comment: How certain are you of those port numbers? I have an old book that lists port 44h as being used by the watchdog timer (Timer 3) on systems with a Micro-Channel Architecture (MCA) bus. Port 44h can read an 8-bit timer value, and port 47h allowed access to a very limited mode control.

Comment: As other people said: There is no standard use of ports 44 and 46 in the standard PC architecture. Can you provide some context about the application? Is it a system specific control program? A copy-protected game? Can you show a short disassembly snippet including access to ports 44/46, so we can make sure you read that code correctly and it is not data that disassembles to IN AL,40h by chance?

Comment: Hi @MichaelKarcher I provided more context; I'm not sure whether it really helps.

Comment: Hi @old_timer thanks for your comment; I totally understand that. Please note that this is not for production code, not even for professional work or curricular studies, I just want to dig into it out of interest. My primary tool at the moment is Turbo Debugger 1.0, which legitimately could be called _retro_.

Comment: Yeah, that disassembly looks sensible, doing extended-precision division with a sequence of bytes from those I/O ports as the dividend.  Machine code that isn't intentionally obfuscated or mixed with data usually disassembles just fine; old_timer frequently over-states the difficulty  (e.g. "at best" x86 machine code disassembles perfectly with the same instruction boundaries the CPU will encounter when executing.)  Although it's a valid concern for old 16-bit stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess seems right. The code tries to set random colors. As it is part of a 256-byte intro, the focus is primarily on code size, not on portability or quality of the random numbers. Possibly this executable was originally meant for a PS/2 or EISA system, and timers 0, 3 and 5 (channel 0 and 2 of the second chip) were free-running. In case you don't have an EISA system, often aliasing will access timers 0, 0 again and 2. This program doesn't enable sound, so timer 2 would be stuck. Furthermore, the code clobbers AH as generated by the DIV instruction at 1BE by executing a MUL instruction at 1CA, so the value read from port 40h isn't used.

To undestand more than this educated guesswork, you would need to contact the author of that code. Considering the bug that AH is clobbered, it seems the code has been created at a demo party under time pressure, and not a lot of "design" went into it. It seems more like "it works well enough".